# pasar un array a una funcion en postgresql

Tags: sql, array, postgresql

estoy creando una funcion en postresql la cual recibe 5 parametros el ultimo parametro es un tipo de dato array que almacenara datos character varying.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ingresar_curso(_nom CHARACTER VARYING, _precio NUMERIC,
_nivel CHARACTER VARYING, _id_usuario SMALLINT,  _array_temas CHARACTER VARYING [])
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO cursos (nombre,precio,nivel,id_usuario) VALUES (_nom,_precio,_nivel,_id_usuario);
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero ejecutar la funcion me da errores e probado muchas maneras de ejecutar la funcion pero sigo sin saber como.

```sql
SELECT ingresar_curso('crud con php y postgresql',20.00,'basico',1,array['']);                                                                       
SELECT ingresar_curso('html',20.00,'basico',1,'{"java","css","html"}');       
SELECT ingresar_curso('html desde cero',20.00,'basico',1,"{'java','css','html'}");    
SELECT ingresar_curso('html desde cero',20.00,'basico',1,ARRAY['html','css']);      
SELECT ingresar_curso('html desde cero',20.00,'basico',1,'{html,css}'::CHARACTER VARYING []);
```

errores como

```sql
ERROR:  no existe la función ingresar_curso(unknown, numeric, unknown, integer, text[])
LINE 2: SELECT ingresar_curso('crud con php y postgresql',20.00,'bas...
               ^
HINT:  Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 9
```

```sql
ERROR:  no existe la columna «{'java','css','html'}»
LINE 2: ...ingresar_curso('html desde cero',20.00,'basico',1,"{'java','...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 59
```

**Si me pueden hacer un ejemplo gracias**

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el error es un tema de conversión explicita(casteo), en este caso con el 4to parámetro (SMALLINT), se pueden poner un poco incómodos!!! ,mira los ejemplos con el casteo implícito, funcionan:

```
SELECT ingresar_curso('crud con php y postgresql',20.00,'basico',1::SMALLINT,array['']);                                                                       
SELECT ingresar_curso('html',20.00,'basico',1::SMALLINT,'{"java","css","html"}');       

SELECT ingresar_curso('html desde cero',20.00,'basico',1::SMALLINT,ARRAY['html','css']);      
SELECT ingresar_curso('html desde cero',20.00,'basico',1::SMALLINT,'{html,css}'::CHARACTER VARYING []);
```